# How to update a bound to property from a service

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service

I'm trying to figure out the best way to have domain logic be isolated in services in an AngularJs application. I'm currently trying to figure out how to propagate changes to bound to properties on models from Services.

As an example if you have a shopping cart in your application and you are using a cartService to manage the users shopping cart then how do you notify bound to properties in the application that the cart has been updated so that if a user adds an item to the cart the rest of your views can update if needed?

Currently every approach I've looked at involves injecting a scope into my service which feels wrong as it would couple my services to AngularJs and I like the idea of my domain being framework agnostic. To solve this problem I could introduce a pub\sub pattern but I wanted to first see how others are handling this.

Is there a way in AngularJs to update bound to properties from services without injecting scope or other angular framework services into your domain services?

Comment: Can you create a [plunker](http://plnkr.co) demonstrating this?

Comment: I have a fiddle with most of the code. I'll create a few versions demonstrating the options I'm considering.

Answer (score 1):

Your services could implement a base method that utilized `$rootScope` to make sure a digest will be run (update your bindings)

in a base service:

```
function MyService(){};

MyService.prototype = {
    applyChanges: function(){
       if(!$rootScope.$$phase) $rootScope.$apply();
    };
};
```

Then use that from methods that change your model. 
If this implementation in angular changes in the future you can then maintain it in one place.

Comment: 3 questions:
1) This would still be coupled to angular though right?
2) Won't this cause all scopes to do a dirty check?
3) Why are you calling $$phase? Isn't that considered something to avoid?